# How to implement Activity comments in Rails?

Tags: getstream-io

What approaches are there to implement comments on feed activities with GetStream using Ruby on Rails?

Are there any plugins for that, 3rd party, etc.? A Google search doesn't yield any results.

I am using the [Stream-rails library](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails).

*Update [19th December, 2015]*

I figured that I could create an `ActivityComment` model, and give it an `activity_id` property, and make use of the `id` property on each `StreamRails::Activity` you give me. However, it would be more convenient if I could persist Activity in my database, too, so I can later get comments by activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use stream-rails and use the Activity mixin for all your model classes, you always have a copy of all activities stored in your database. In your case you can retrieve all comments related to one activity if you keep a reference to it. The best way to store that reference is not `activity_id` but `foreign_id`.

One way to do this is the following: add a field in your `ActivityComment` and call it `parent_foreign_id`. Assign to that field the `foreign_id` of the commented activity.

When you want to retrieve all comments for one activity, you only need to fetch all `ActivityComment` models that have `parent_foreign_id` equal to the activity `foreign_id`.